# Twitter Bot Error - Unhandled Promise Rejection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I wrote this twitter weather bot, which worked fine since last month, but an hour ago it crashed and I can't seem to bring it back up.

Can anyone simply explain me what it is and also what the error is, when it arises and what I have to check to get rid of this warning?

I did search up how to fix an "unhandled promise rejection" but could not find out what it is.

```
const Twit = require('twit');
const config = require('./config');
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

async function setup(location) {
    const options = {
        url: "http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json",
        qs: { 
            key: API_KEY,
            q: location
        },
        json: true
    };
    let result = await rp(options);
    let condition = result.current.condition.text;
    let tweetText = `The condition in ${location} is currently ${condition}, and the temperature is ${result.current.temp_c}°C.`;
    console.log(tweetText);
    sendTweet(tweetText)
}

function sendTweet(text) {
    const T = new Twit(config);
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    const tweet = {
        status: '[' + r + '] ' + text
    }

    T.post('statuses/update', tweet);
}
setup('Colombo');
```

````
2019-08-21T06:41:52.820595+00:00 app[scheduler.8141]: at setup (/app/bot.js:25:36)

2019-08-21T06:41:52.820597+00:00 app[scheduler.8141]: at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

2019-08-21T06:41:52.820719+00:00 app[scheduler.8141]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

2019-08-21T06:41:52.820834+00:00 app[scheduler.8141]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

2019-08-21T06:41:52.903455+00:00 heroku[scheduler.8141]: State changed from up to complete

2019-08-21T06:41:52.880762+00:00 heroku[scheduler.8141]: Process exited with status 0```
````

Comment: `Cannot read property 'condition' of undefined`. So apparently the response to your http-request doesn't give you the answer you expect. I'd assume the structure differs. To prevent the warning (and just see the error) you could use something like `setup('Colombo').catch( (e) => console.error(e) );`

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'condition' of undefined
    at setup (C:\projects\shameel-twitter-bot\bot.js:25:36)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
``` It's more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the api with:

```
let result = await rp(options);
```

You are setting result as a promise to wait for the API call, but your request is not accepted for some reason and then you are getting a promise rejection but not handling.

Please use:

```
await rp(options).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

So you can log your error, then we can investigate your error.

---------- EDIT ------------

Just tested it myself, and we are getting a 503 HTTP Status code:

[Here is the log print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d04uM.png)

It means that the service is not available, not receiving requests.

---------- EDIT -----------

It is working again, tried here, I'm getting 200 HTTP Status code and a good response, now you should be good to go

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'condition' of undefined
    at setup (C:\projects\shameel-twitter-bot\bot.js:25:36)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```                                                                                                                                             I see, this is whats showing up

Comment: Edited my answer, just tried here and it is returning 503 HTTP Status code, service is unavailable. This API is probably going through some down time.

Comment: Just got back up actually :)

Comment: Alright man, I'll check it again tmmr. I appreciate the help.